# Getting HTTP 404 Error while using @PathVariable annotation in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

I am a beginner in Spring MVC and trying to execute a demo spring program given in tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dDWNTR0-rns&list=PLBgMUB7xGcO31B2gBmy1igpZn6LK78-CJ&index=9

While running the program i am getting HTTP 404 error and description is "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists". Can someone please help me to resolve this issue.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>FirstSpringMVCAnnotations</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  

</web-app>
```

**spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package = "com.demo.controller"/> 

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id = "viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />  
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>  
    </bean>  
</beans>
```

**PathVariableDemoController**

```
package com.demo.controller;

import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/greeting")
public class PathVariableDemoController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello/{username}/{countryname}")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld(@PathVariable("username") String username, @PathVariable("countryname") String countryname) {
        System.out.println("Inside PathVariableDemoController...");
        ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView("Greetings");
        String msg = "Hello " + username + " You are from " + countryname;
        modelView.addObject("greetingsMessage", msg);
        System.out.println("End PathVariableDemoController helloWorld()...");
        return modelView;
    }
}
```

**Greetings.jsp**

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Message is: ${greetingsMessage}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**Project Structure:**

[image]

**Error Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: try changing `<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />` to `<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF" />`  (remove leading slash)

Comment: tried this but getting same error :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The import for ModelAndView in above Controller is of portlet package.

```
import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;
```

Changing the import for ModelAndView as below in Controller class fixed this issue.

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
```